# ruby on rails converting from sqlite3 to mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

My installation

- Ubuntu 10.10
- Rails 3
- gem = sqlite3 and sqlite3-ruby
- gem = mysql2

Now I created a application called mytestapp, using

```
rails new mytestapp
```

As usual with rails 3 it defaults to using sqlite3 database. Now I wanted to change the database for mytestapp so that it uses MySql database.

I made changes here

- database.yml
- gemfile - I added *gem 'mysql2'* and removed *gem 'sqlite3'*

My new database.yml looked something like this

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mytestapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: mytestapp
  password: hacked
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Now I goto *localhost:3000* and click on the **about application's development environment**
I get the following error

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

MySql user **mytestapp** has proper permissions for the database.

Infact when I create a new rails app using the following

```
rails new anotherapp -d mysql
```

It works great. What can be missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ran `bundle install` after editing your `Gemfile`?

If you did, then try to run the following command to see what's the difference between your hand-edited application and the new you created with -d mysql:

```
diff /path/to/hand-edited-app /path/to/rails-created-mysql-app
```

Comment: ok the diff command showed me that gemfile.lock also had sqlite as its dependency. So should I change it by hand or use some command. Maybe bundle install. I have no idea.

Comment: You change Gemfile.lock by running `bundle install`.